# Using Jcarousel with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, jcarousel

I've got model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :firstname, type: String
  field :avatar, type: String

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

I want users to select their avatars from the list of images i've provided,

[image]

to do that i'm using Jcarousel (connected, [link](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/)) which appears in popup window.
And I'm totally lost implementing this, any ideas?

Comment: @apneadiving i tried to add f.file_field :avatar to the _form.html.erb, but it's not enough for me in this situation, what can you advise?

Comment: does anybody has got an idea?